# Add infobox button on selectmenu in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the following code:

Also see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k36snme1/

JS:

```
$( "#solImport-solution" ).selectmenu({
    width: "auto",
    change: function( event, data ) {
    console.log("TEST");
    },
    addClass: "overflow"
});
```

html:

```
<select name="category" id="solImport-solution">
  <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">Select a Solution</option>
  <option value="test">Test1</option>
</select>
```

I have this selectmenu from jquery and I'd like to have a small button to the right side with a questionmark for giving infos. How can I achieve that? Is there any build-in function for this?

[image: infobox]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Go with simply html css instead of asking here. If you want to build an own website you should learn HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease and rapid development, I'd use bootstrap. You can add another `<div>` next to the input and add a "tooltip" on hover.

[Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)